# How to explain a strength of the sphere in simple terms?

Tags: material-science, stress-strain

In our high school's physics book (in Turkish), a strength of the material is discussed in simple terms given by Galileo: The strength of the material is proportional to its cross-section area divided by its volume.

There is no problem for a calculation for regular shapes such as cubes, cylinders. But the book's example goes further to include a calculation for a sphere. I don't understand its logic taking the cross section area of the sphere through its circumference. Why is it not taking its contact point or any other cross-sectional area? Where will the sphere likely fracture first, from its circumference or from its contact point or any other point? Here is the book's page regarding its calculations:

[image]

Comment: Don't understand at all why your textbook is saying that the strength of the material is proportional to cross sectional area divided by volume. If the opposite ends of an object are subjected to tension or compression, then the maximum stress should be proportional to the cross sectional area of an object with constant cross section. Don't see where the volume of the object comes into play. Does you textbook give any justification for saying that the maximum stress (i.e., strength) is proportional to cross sectional area divided by volume?

Comment: I think it is just the comparison between the same object with a different dimension. If we increase the dimension of the object, by the Galileo's Square-Cube law (https://www.dinosaurtheory.com/scaling.html), it becomes less weak. the book may try to show that the strength is inversely proportional to its height.

Comment: Maybe, but as you pointed out it, for the case of a sphere it doesn't seem to make much sense to choose the cross-sectional area through the center of the sphere rather than at a point near its contact point with whatever is stressing it.